# Placing 2 DIV side by side even if the page is too small

Tags: css, html

Hi im trying to put 2 `DIV` side by side

```
+--------------------------------+ +--------------------------------+
|                                | |                                |
|                                | |                                |
|            400px               | |            355px               |
|                                | |                                |
|                                | |                                |
|                                | |                                |
+--------------------------------+ +--------------------------------+

.header{
    background-image: url('../img/button-bg.png');
    padding: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 36px;
}



.div1
{
    width: 400px;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}


.div2
{

    width:355px;
}
```

I need both `DIV` to be able to clear the header so I can't use absolute position

I tried the float left attribute, but when the page is too small the other div is going under the first div. I was wondering if it was possible to do so.

edit : When the screen is too small, I want the horizontal bar to appear

Comment: What did you try? (Show us some code)

Comment: You didn't explain what you'd like to happen. Do you want the 2nd dive to overlap the first, do you want them stretch the body and make a horizontal scroll bar on the page, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `display:inline-block;` on the divs and `white-space: nowrap;` on their parent.

```
.header div{
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.header{
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-image: url('../img/button-bg.png');
    padding: 0px;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    height: 36px;
}
.div1{
    width: 400px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}    
.div2{
    width:355px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mowglisanu/a6YNY/

Answer (score 4):

[Yes, it is possible:](http://jsfiddle.net/szKd4/)

```
<div class="outer">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

```
.outer {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.outer div {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: op doesn't want to use float

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: No, OP is probably just not using float correctly

Comment: he doesn't want the second div to be on a new line when the page gets smaller

Comment: @UğurGümüşhan: And my answer doesn't show that behaviour. My guess is that the OP is combining pixel margins with percentage widths, which is doomed to fail.

Answer (score -2):

You should use a table (or two spans, side by side) if you don't want your elements to float.
Firstly, learn what inline and block elements are. div is a block element and span is an inline element. div is to use as a block element. it's designed to act as a block element. it's supposed to have full width unless you specify otherwise. span is an inline element and it allows other elements to be next to itself. you can search "inline vs block html" for more info

to see the scroll bars, set the overflow css attribute of the **container of these elements** to scroll. 
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Comment: No, you should use a table if you want a table